# how to copy one data table into another with customize ways

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
Series_name Age value
------------------------
Per_03  5.00    13.7000
Per_03  5.50    13.6000
Per_03  6.00    13.6000
Per_03  6.50    13.6000
Per_03  7.00    13.6000
Per_03  7.50    13.7000
Per_03  8       13.8000
Per_10  5.00    14.2000
Per_10  5.50    14.1000
Per_10  6.00    14.0000
Per_10  6.50    13.9000
Per_10  7.00    14.0000
Per_10  7.50    14.1000
Per_10  8.00    14.2000
Per_25  5.00    14.5000
Per_25  5.50    14.6000
Per_25  6.00    14.5000
Per_25  6.50    14.6000
```

I have datatable like this and i Have to make each different series name as datacolunm and their respective value into their age, series name column row-wise  and Expected result is and here Series name will have to take dynamically  like how much different series name in column each series name will become column name and series name is not hard-coded .....

```
age     Per_03  Per_10  Per_25
-------------------------------
5.00    13.7000 14.2000 14.5000
5.50    13.6000 14.1000 14.6000
6.00    13.6000 14.0000 14.5000
6.50    13.6000 13.9000 14.6000
7.00    13.6000 14.0000 14.6000
7.50    13.7000 14.1000 14.7000
8.00    13.7000 14.2000 14.8000
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: So what's your question exactly?

Comment: i have added my expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5bbb3/1/0)

```
SELECT
    age,
    Per_03 = MAX(CASE WHEN Series_Name = 'Per_03' THEN vaue END),
    Per_10 = MAX(CASE WHEN Series_Name = 'Per_10' THEN vaue END),
    Per_25 = MAX(CASE WHEN Series_Name = 'Per_25' THEN vaue END)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY age
ORDER BY age
```

---

If the `Series_Name`s are unknown, you can use a dynamic crosstab:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5bbb3/2/0)

```
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 =
'SELECT
    age
'

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN Series_Name = ''' +  Series_Name + ''' THEN value END) AS [' + Series_Name + ']' + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT Series_Name FROM tbl
)t
ORDER BY Series_Name
SELECT @sql3 = 
'FROM tbl
GROUP BY age
ORDER BY age'

PRINT (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

Comment: but here series name should not be hard-coded it must be dynamice

Comment: I included a dynamic approach.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, If you have SQL SERVER 2005 or later then you could use a dynamic PIVOT as follows:

```
DECLARE @ColumnList VARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

-- Create a list of distinct Series_names which will become column headers
SELECT @ColumnList = COALESCE(@ColumnList + '], [','[') + CAST(T.Series_name AS VARCHAR(12)) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Series_name FROM YourTable) T
SET @ColumnList = @ColumnList + ']'

SET @SQL = '
SELECT
  [Age], ' + @ColumnList + '
FROM
(  
  SELECT
    A.Age,
    A.Series_Name,
    A.Value
  FROM
      YourTable A
)  T
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Value)
    FOR T.Series_Name IN (' + @ColumnList + ')
) AS PVT'

EXEC (@SQL)
```